# What prefix to use when indexing SecureRandom string column

Tags: mysql, ruby, indexing

I have a DB column (type `varchar(255)`) that stores a URL-safe base 64 string produced by `SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64`. The method call uses the default values, so the result should be [16 bytes or **22 characters** in length](https://apidock.com/ruby/SecureRandom/urlsafe_base64/class).

The base64 value is used to look up records when a user hits the site, to mask DB IDs. I need an index for this column because of this lookup, however I don't want to index the entire column because that *could* be inefficient storage-wise.

What's the best approach to determining the optimal index prefix to use in this case? What I'm thinking right now is something like this:

1. Create sample data with about 100k records to simulate production data
2. Add an index for the base 64 column with a prefix (say 8 characters)
3. Run `EXPLAIN` on a lookup on the base 64 column to see how many
   records need to be inspected
4. Adjust the index up or down and re-do step 3.
5. Choose a prefix size that balances (a) storage requirements and (b) number of records returned with matching hits.

The issue here is that I know `SecureRandom` produces unique base 64 strings, but I'm not sure *how unique* they are. Eg, out of 100k records, if I use a prefix of 8 characters, will that prefix be shared by 10 records or 100?

Some more specific questions about my approach:

1. Is 100k records enough of a sample to pick a good prefix size?
2. If I did apply an index *without* using a prefix, is my suspicion that this is bad storage-wise correct?
3. What's a reasonable number of records to expect to have to query the table directly, and still benefit from an index?

**Notes**:

- My database is MySQL (actually Percona)
- `SecureRandom` comes from Ruby
- I'm assuming that the URL-safe feature of `SecureRandom` isn't changing the uniqueness characteristics of the base 64 output.

Comment: Why do you care about uniqueness? As long as they are evenly distributed, the index will produce a balanced number of buckets and will be efficient when retrieving data. And I would guess SecureRandom produces rather balanced values.

Comment: Also, a table with 100k rows is quite small for today's standards. I wouldn't worry about index performance at this level. If you had 100 millions rows I would definitively focus on tweaking performance. But with just 100k rows... even if you used the full length column (255 bytes) you'll be perfectly OK.

Comment: Why not use `SecureRandom.uuid` then they will be unique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Results

I decided to follow the steps I outlined in the question. As a result I got the information I needed to choose an index prefix.

Two changes resulted from this experiment:

1. I reduced the size of the column from `255` to `22` (also suggested by @Rick James). See details in the question for why the data is never more than 22 characters.
2. I added an index on the column with a prefix of 8 characters. The charset is utf8mb4, so the key size will not be directly proportional to the number of characters in the prefix.

### Experiment details

I tested prefixes of length 1, 2, 4, 8 and 16 characters and used `EXPLAIN` to see what the a lookup on the column would do. I also tested with no index as a baseline. My experiment was based on a set of 100k records. I could have tested with more records, but for my purposes, it wasn't necessary to get more precise.

Here are some highlights of the experiment:

- Without an index, the query on the `SecureRandom` column does a table scan.
- With a 1 character prefix, MySQL has to scan roughly 3200 records of 100k.
- With a 2 character prefix, MySQL has to scan 79 records.
- With a 4 character prefix, MySQL gets the exact record immediately without doing a lookup on the table.

Beyond the 4 character prefix, with a data set of 100k and based on the characteristics of `SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64` I can't get more precise. Based on the current size of the table in production and a rough idea of its growth rate, we decided that a prefix of 8 characters would serve us well into the future, while economizing on disk and memory usage.

### Alternatives

Through this exploration I also learned about MySQL's index selectivity feature. This would allow, using the same sample set of 100k records, to test the number of records retrieved for each prefix length, without having to run migrations to add/drop the different indices before each test. For example, to test the selectivity of a 4-character prefix:

```
SELECT count(*) AS count, LEFT(uuid_column, 4) AS prefix
  FROM string_prefix_test GROUP BY count DESC LIMIT 10;
```

More details on index selectivity can be found in the 2012 edition of *High Performance MySQL* at p 160.

### Future work

Next I'm going to be looking into prefixes for indices of `varchar` columns with data that doesn't have the uniqueness characteristics of `SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64`. That's going to be more challenging only because getting a representative data set is harder.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a random number, correct?  Not encryption.

Do *not* use a prefix; although it will shrink the index size some, it will invalidate the usage of the index in many cases.  True, 22 bytes is longer than an 8-char string or a 4-byte `INT`.  But the downside of failure to use the index is worse.

The default of 16 (22) is sufficient to make the random string unique enough to avoid accidental collisions.

Don't say `VARCHAR(255)` if the max is 22.  Say `CHAR(22)` if fixed length or `VARCHAR(22)` if you allow the user to choose a length up to 16.

Do say `CHARACTER SET ascii COLLATE ascii_bin` for the column.  This will avoid (1) overhead of utf8 and (2) the mistake of case folding.

If you are going to have an index on a billion of these items, then there will be significant performance issues, as discussed [*here*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/uuid) (though in a different context).  A million rows is probably not an issue -- it depends on when the index becomes bigger than can be cached in RAM in the buffer_pool.

(If I recall the formula correctly, for 8 chars as you describe, there would be one chance in 300K that an index with 300K entries would include a duplicate.  But that's not the issue.)